# What parts of Java SE is NOT used in Android development?

Tags: java, android

threads are not used, generics are not used.

Android uses only fraction of Java features, i know this, but what parts are NOT used?

p.s. this is not opinion type of question - i m asking about actual parts, i.e. specific answer, facts.

Comment: advance java is not use here in android like Swing,Hybernet,Struts are not use in android all basic part of java use here in android

Comment: who sad you thread are not use in android look here RunAtuithread are most popular of thread which i think you not know ....

Comment: Look at here this link https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/create-threadpool.html

Comment: Look this is simple example are here http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

Answer (score 4):

> my opinion: threads are not used, generics are not used.

That's wrong. The whole `java.util.concurrent` package was ported up to java 1.6. And Generics are also full supported. What is not yet in, is the new java 1.8 features, like `streams` and `lambda`, and part of java 1.7, the new `File.NIO 2`

Answer (score 0):

How about AWT and Swing? Android has it's own UI Framework.